# Why do the names of some Japanese prefectures contain 『しま』when, clearly, they are not island prefectures?

Tags: etymology

Why do the names of some Japanese prefectures contain 『しま』when, clearly, they are not island prefectures?

For example, 広島　means "spacious/vast island," doesn't it? However, Hiroshima is not an island... And there are more examples like this: 福**島**、徳**島**、and 鹿児**島**.

I hope you can clear this up. Thank you!

Comment: Is  Rhode Island  an island state?

Comment: Highly related or duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23810/why-is-%e5%b3%b6-used-in-the-name-of-some-cities

Comment: @l'électeur to be fair, Rhode Island's name is the result of people abbreviating the full name, rather than "island" having a different meaning

Comment: @l'électeur as Leebo points out, the full name of the state is [State of Rhode Island and Providence Plantations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhode_Island). Are you suggesting the Japanese prefectures with 島 are named after an island included in their territory, or what's your point?